# Epiphany shuts down as it is loading

Tags: debian

On my Raspberry Pi, Epiphany starts up and then after "loading 'Most Visited'..." it closes. I reinstalled Epiphany after doing a full update, and the same thing still is happening. Other programs are running OK, including the Dillo browser.

Answer (score 1):

If during startup you quickly close the tab that says "Most Visited", I have been able to run Epiphany without issue.  When mine starts it tries to open two tabs; "Most Visited" and a tab called "Blank page".  You have to wait until both tabs are visible and then close the "Most visited" tab as quickly as possible.  Sometimes takes several tries.

Not sure what that tells us but I didn't start having issues until I upgraded from Wheezy to Jessie.  Now that I know what to do, I can get it started without too much difficulty.